# Use Microsoft.AspNetCore dll in text generation t4 file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4

I'm trying to use t4 file to generate some code for my ASP.Core web api. I need to Execute following code in `.tt` file

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Runtime" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
    <#
        // put cs code here 

        var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "D:\\work\\AITeF\\AdministratorModule\\AdministratorModule\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.1\\AdministratorModule.dll"));

        var controlleractionlist = asm.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public))
            .Where(m => !m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true).Any())
            .Select(x => new { Controller = x.DeclaringType.Name, Action = x.Name, ReturnType = x.ReturnType.Name, Attributes = String.Join(",", x.GetCustomAttributes().Select(a => a.GetType().Name.Replace("Attribute", ""))) })
            .OrderBy(x => x.Controller).ThenBy(x => x.Action).ToList();
    #>
```

However, I always get an error that namespace 'Controller' could not be found. How can I reference this `.dll` to execute my code without errors.

Answer (score 0):

After you've added a valid path for the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll` You need to either import the namespace for `Controller` or fully qualify it

```
<#@ assembly name="a:\valid\path\to\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
// ...
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller" #>

// or fully qualified
    var controlleractionlist = asm.GetTypes()
        .Where(type => typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
```